# React-Navigation - getting the previous screen name when having nested navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm in a screen component and I want to get the name of the screen I'm coming from (the previous screen).

Usually you'd do something like this

```
const routes = navigation.getState()?.routes;
const prevRoute = routes[routes.length - 2]; // -2 because -1 is the current route
```

However, my app has nested navigators, so it doesn't work.

How do I achieve this?

For example, if I want to get the current route I do something like this. But for previous I can't figure it out.

```
 const navigationState = navigation.getState()
  const route = state?.routes[state?.index];
    const subRouteIndex = route?.state?.index;
    let subRoute;
    if (subRouteIndex !== undefined) {
      subRoute = route?.state?.routes[subRouteIndex];
      dispatch(setHighlightedOptionID(subRoute?.name ?? ""))
    }
```

Comment: Could you try passing the screen name as a param to the next screen? For instance `navigation.navigate('to-screen', {prev: 'current-screen-name'})`. And then on the target screen: `const {prev} = route?.params || {};`